# Is the perfectness of Fourier-Mukai kernels proved by Toen?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ho.history-overview, derived-categories

In Toen's paper [The homotopy theory of dg-algebras and derived Morita theory](http://www.mi.ras.ru/~akuznet/dgcat/Toen%20The%20homotopy%20theory%20of%20dg-algebras%20and%20derived%20Morita%20theory.pdf), Theorem 8.15, he essentially proved the following result.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two smooth and proper schemes over $k$. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be an object in $D_{qcoh}(X\times Y)$ such that the integral transform
>   $$
> \Phi_{\mathcal{E}}:=Rp_{Y,*}(p^*_X(-)\otimes^{L}\mathcal{E})
> $$
>   maps $D_{perf}(X)$ to $D_{perf}(Y)$. Then $\mathcal{E}$ itself is a perfect complex on $X\times Y$.

I wonder if this result is due to Toen or it already exists in previous works (by himself or other authors.)